# In spring xml config,how to automatically get the current bean's ID value?

Tags: spring

I use quartz in spring xml,  I have many config like above config~~

I want to known ,automatically get the id value of the current bean

Not every time I hand-written the value of the current bean!!

```
<bean id="openBaiduTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail">
        <bean p:targetObject-ref="baiduManager" p:targetMethod="createOpenBaiDu" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean" />
    </property>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="#{p_schedule['openBaiduTrigger.cronExpression']}" />
</bean>
```

[image: In xml config,how to get the current bean's ID value?]

Comment: Can you give some more details? what do you mean current bean?

Comment: This property belongs to the bean @Tomer

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are doing here. You are trying to get the id of a bean in the spring config automeaticlly? You are the one to configuring the bean, so you also gave the id. what is the point to do it automatically if you configured this bean hard coded? do you wish that bean to be automatically created to? or it need to be configured on the spring config xml file? @feilong

Comment: @Tomer Simple sentence: I want to be lazy, I do not want to hand-write each cronExpression property, whitch value is #{p_schedule ['**current bean's id**.cronExpression']}